# Сkeditor Как загрузить картинку из интернета на мой сервер?

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

Использую визуальный редактор Ckeditor. Возможно ли с помощью Ckeditor загрузить картинку из интернета в мой сервер? Т.е. дать ckeditor ссылку вида `http://301-1.ru/img_files/2015_01_27_114ba310cf01f670da1720c62093c547.jpg`, чтобы ckeditor загрузил эту картинку на мой сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действующие [плагины](http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all) и дополнения для Ckeditor не позволяют сделать это. Все расширенные файловые менеджеры загружают изображения с Вашего компьютера на Ваш сервер через стандартную форму загрузки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.: В принципе, Вы можете изменить текущий функционал редактора, дописав его под свои нужды или написать свой плагин, позволяющий делать желаемое.

Comment: спасибо за ответ,я именно это и хотел узнать Ckeditor позволяет или нет

Answer (score 0):

Есть plugin для CKEditor, называется [Image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image).
Данный плагин позволяет указывать ссылку на внешний сайт в качестве источника изображения. В описании об этом не сказано, но в своем проекте я его использую.

Comment: Да данный плагин позволяет указывать ссылку на внешний сайт,но  это не поможет мне,я хочу сохранить эту картинку у меня в сервере,а то внешний сайт может удалить картинку,а я останусь без картинки)))

Comment: @ArsenAsulyan согласен. Извините, невнимательно прочел ваш вопрос.